# Show slidedown messages one after the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show a slide down alerts using angularjs. Here is my code:

```
function LoginController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.alerts = [{
      name: "Alert 01 something something"
    },
    {
      name: "Alert 02 something something"
    }
  ];

  $scope.currentAlert = {
  name: "Something something"
  };

  $scope.showFeedback = function() {
    $("#notification-alert").slideDown(500);
    $timeout(() => {
      $("#notification-alert").slideUp();
    }, 1500)
  };

  $scope.goThroughAlert();
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
     <div class="alert alert-info my-feedback" id="notification-alert">
        <div>{{currentAlert.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to loop through the alerts array and slide down the messages one by one using some code like this.

```
 $scope.goThroughAlert = function() {
    for (i = 0, length = $scope.alerts.length; i < length; i++) {
      let current = $scope.alerts[i];
      $scope.currentAlert.name = current.name;
      $scope.showFeedback();
    }
  }
```

But it only show alert 02. Could you please tell me what I did wrong here? I want to show alert 01 first and after alert 01 slide up, show alert 02 and so on if there more than 2 items in the array. Here is the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/jcpw1nhk/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is running instantaneously, so the current alert is updated to the second alert immediately after it's updated to the first alert.

I'm not very familiar with angularjs, but here is a naive fix which illustrates the issue:

```
  $scope.goThroughAlert = function() {
    let current = $scope.alerts[0];
    $scope.currentAlert.name = current.name;
    $scope.showFeedback();
    
    $timeout(() => {
      let current = $scope.alerts[1];
      $scope.currentAlert.name = current.name;
      $scope.showFeedback();
    }, 2000)
  }
```

You'll need to delay the alerts in some way.

Comment: Yes I think so too. I'm trying to look for a way to delay the For loop so it moves to the next item only when the slide up of the current item is completed. Not sure how though. Thanks anyway.